# Creating Custom Query using custom (ACF) field to display relational data in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to creat a Custom Query using custom (ACF) field to display relational data in Wordpress.  I get nothing displayed. I dont get any errors either.

I have two custom post types, "town" & "event"

The "event" post type has a custom relationship field (using ACF) named "town", where I can relate an event with a specific town.

On the page for displaying a town (single-town.php), I am trying to display all the events happening in that town.

```
<?php
 get_header();
 ?>
 <br>

 /* display the current town, title, feature image, and description */
<?php
 while (have_posts()){
  the_post();
  $title = get_the_title(); /* use this var in custom query below */
  ?><h2><?php echo $title ?> </H2>
  <hr><?php
  the_post_thumbnail('large');
  the_content();
  }?>
  <br>
  <?php 

 /*create a custom query to fetch all the events for that town */
 $posts = get_posts(array(
  'paged'=> get_query_var('paged',25),
  'posts_per_page' => 25,
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'orderby'=> 'title',
  'order'=> 'ASC',
  'meta_key'=> 'town',
  'meta_query'=> array(
         array(
      'key'=> 'town',
      'compare'=> '=',
      'value'=> $title
  ));
));

 /* display custom query results */

if( $posts ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ):
        setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; 

 wp_reset_postdata();
 get_footer();
?>
```

I have also tried using:

```
 $eventQuery = new WP_Query(array(
 'paged'=> get_query_var('paged',25),
 'posts_per_page' => 25,
 'post_type' => 'event',
 'orderby'=> 'title',
 'order'=> 'ASC',

 'meta_key'=> 'town',
 'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
     'key'=> 'town',
     'compare'=> '=',
     'value'=> $title
))
));

while ($eventQuery->have_posts()){
$eventQuery->the_post();
$eventQuery->the_title();
}
```

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: Oh yeah, that might be helpful.  I get nothing. Not even an error. I will update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Relationship field saves data as an array of IDs, it doesn't save the post title. So while your second example using WP_Query is closer, it won't find any matches because your comparing the value with the current post's title. Compare with the ID instead:

```
$eventQuery = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'town', 
            'value'   => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the assist!